# Creating a directory path not working with PHPs mkdir?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, mkdir

I have the following directory `c:/files` and I'm trying to create a wrapper function which emulates mkdir()'s functionality except works on more then one folder e.g.

mkdir works fine on the following:

```
mkdir('c:/files/games', 0777);
```

But not on this:

```
mkdir('c:/files/games/say/yes', 0777);
```

Heres some rough code to further describe what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function mmkdir($path, $chmod = 0777) {
/* do some loop or something with mkdir()? here */
}

mmkdir('C:/tmp/something/something');

mmkdir('C:/tmp/go/something');

mmkdir('C:/tmp/yes');
```

Comment: do you have the intermediate "say" folder created?

Comment: Your method signature is screwy. Try removing $path variable.

Comment: no, i think mkdir works by only creating the last folder in the given path, which is why I'm think I'd need to perhaps make a wrapper function to handle that?

Comment: @Joe: Huh? Why would he do that?

Comment: @Tomalak, it's been edited since my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the `mkdir()` function with the recursive parameter set to `TRUE`. For example:

```
mkdir('c:/files/games/say/yes', 0777, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 6):

> mkdir works fine on the following:
>
> `mkdir('c:/files/games', 0777);`
>
> But not on this:
>
> `mkdir('c:/files/games/say/yes', 0777);`

Wrong, [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/mkdir) has a third parameter

> bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, **bool $recursive = false** [, resource $context ]]] )

```
mkdir('c:/files/games/say/yes', 0777, true);
```

This makes your custom function obsolete. However, if you *really* want to create your own function (which in my opinion is not worth to think about, because it already exists built-in), it should look like

```
function recursive_mkdir ($path, $chmod = 0777) {
  $parent = dirname($path);
  if (!file_exists($parent)) recursive_mkdir($parent, $chmod);
  mkdir($path, $chmod);
}
```

Comment: +1: I lol'd. :) When will people learn to _read the documentation_ for functions they use? It's astounding...

Comment: I don't know.. Especially its much faster, than writing a question at SO ;)

Comment: ...and I dread to think how long the guy was working on the "problem" before posting it here.